# How to extract all PowerBI users and workspace access using the PowerBI API or Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, powerbi, portal

New to Power BI. Trying to get a report of the Users who have access for each Dashboards. Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Get-PowerBIWorkspace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoftpowerbimgmt.workspaces/get-powerbiworkspace?view=powerbi-ps) from [Microsoft Power BI Cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps) to get list of workspaces and then list the members of the underlying Office 365 group (unless you are using the new preview workspaces, which has no underlying Office 365 group) using [`Get-UnifiedGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/get-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet. To be able to use it, you need to [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps). Then enumerate the groups, enumerate current group members, and export them to a CSV (or process the result the way you want). If you have rights, provide `-Scope Organization` parameter, or omit it to get a list of your workspaces.

```
Import-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt

$password = "xxxxxxxx" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "xxxxxxxx@example.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange `
    -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ `
    -Credential $credential `
    -Authentication Basic `
    -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $Session

$Groups = Get-PowerBIWorkspace #-Scope Organization
$Groups | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_
    Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity $group.Name -LinkType Members -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object {
        $member = $_
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            Member = $member.Name
            Group = $group.Name
        }
    }
} | Export-CSV "D:\\PowerBIGroupMembers.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Remove-PSSession $Session

Disconnect-PowerBIServiceAccount
```

Comment: Hi @Andrey Nikolov, the script worked, if I open in Excel the result on the CSV file was only this "ï»¿", if I open on notepad was blank, can you help me please?

Comment: This will work only for classic workspaces, which is highly unlikely to be the case now.

Comment: Oh I see, I'm sorry for that. I'm really noob for powershell scripst. Could you help us all to get that same result but for the case we're now?

Answer (score 5):

Below is the script I created. First change the username and password for your PowerBI credentials. The script collects the results and then opens two Out Grid windows (Workspaces and Workspace Users). You can then copy/paste the grid results into excel. This doesn't export shared reports and dashboards.

I have two PBI powershell modules installed. I think this script uses only the MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.

Check if you have the PBI modules.

```
get-module -ListAvailable | where {$_.Name -like '*BI*'}
```

And to check for the cmdlets available.

```
get-command -module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Admin | sort CommandType, name
get-command -module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Capacities | sort CommandType, name
get-command -module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Data | sort CommandType, name
get-command -module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Profile | sort CommandType, name
get-command -module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Reports | sort CommandType, name
get-command -module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt.Workspaces | sort CommandType, name
get-command -module PowerBIPS | sort CommandType, name
```

**PBI WORKSPACES & PERMISSIONS**

```
#****************
#------------------------------------------------------
# --> PBI WORKSPACES & PERMISSIONS
#
# Export PBI results to grid for copy/paste to Excel table
# * All groups (Active/Deleted)
# * All workspaces (Active)
# * All workspace permissions
#
# RestAPI call for each workspace (Group Users) 
# * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/getgroupusers
#
#------------------------------------------------------ 


#****************
#------------------------------------------------------
# --> PBI Connection
#------------------------------------------------------ 
Write-Host " PBI credentials ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

## PBI credentials 

$password = "myPassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "myemail@domain.com" 
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)

## PBI connect 

Connect-PowerBIServiceAccount -Credential $credential

# Login-PowerBI


#****************
#------------------------------------------------------
# --> Workspace info 
# 
# * Get-PowerBIWorkspace > "WARNING: Defaulted to show top 100 workspaces. Use -First & -Skip or -All to retrieve more results."
# * Grid exported for workspaces
#------------------------------------------------------ 
Write-Host " Workspace info ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
    
## List all groups, Select ID desired for Variables section 
## PBIWorkspace properties values are NULL if Scope is not set to Organization 
# Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -Filter "tolower(name) eq 'BI Team POC - DEV'" 

# SET
$Groups = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -All | SORT @{Expression="Type"; Descending=$True}, Name

$Groups_deleted = $Groups | SELECT Id, Name, Type, State | WHERE State -EQ 'Deleted'
$Groups = $Groups | SELECT Id, Name, Type, State | WHERE State -NE 'Deleted'
$GroupWorkspaces = $Groups | WHERE Type -eq 'Workspace' 

# PRINT
$Groups_deleted | Select Id, Name, Type, State | ft –auto 
$Groups | Select Id, Name, Type, State | ft –auto 
$GroupWorkspaces | Select Id, Name, Type | ft –auto 
Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -Name "BI Team Sandbox" | Select Id, Name, Type | ft –auto 

# OUT GRID
$GroupsWorkspaces | Select Id, Name, Type | Out-GridView 
$Groups | Select Id, Name, Type | Out-GridView
$Groups_deleted | Select Id, Name, Type, State | Out-GridView


#------------------------------------------------------ 
## LOOP FOLDERS ##################
# * RestAPI call for each workspace (Group Users) 
# * Grid exported for workspace user access
#------------------------------------------------------ 

# Clear variable before loop to reseat array data collector 
clear-variable -name WorkspaceUsers

Write-Host " Looping ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkGreen

foreach ($GroupWorkspaceId in $GroupWorkspaces.Id) {

    $WorkspaceObject = Get-PowerBIWorkspace -Scope Organization -Id $GroupWorkspaceId
    $pbiURL = "https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/$GroupWorkspaceId/users"
    $WorkspaceObject | Select Id, Name, Type | ft –auto 

    Write-Host ($WorkspaceObject.Name +" | "+ $WorkspaceObject.Type)  -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue
    Write-Host $GroupWorkspaceId -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue
    Write-Host $pbiURL -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Blue


#****************
#------------------------------------------------------
# --> 1. API Call for WORKSPACE USERS  
#------------------------------------------------------ 
    Write-Host " API Call ..." -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
     
    ## API call
    $resultJson = Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod –Url $pbiURL –Method GET 
    $resultObject = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $resultJson 

    ## Collect data fields for each loop
    $WorkspaceUsers += $resultObject.Value | 
    SELECT @{n='WorkspaceId';e={$GroupWorkspaceId}}, 
            @{n='Workspace';e={$WorkspaceObject.Name}}, 
            displayName, 
            emailAddress, 
            @{n='UserRole';e={$_.groupUserAccessRight}}, 
            @{n='Principle';e={$_.principalType}} |
        SELECT Workspace, displayName, UserRole, Principle, emailAddress | 
        SORT UserRole, displayName 
    
    ## Print loop results
    $WorkspaceUsers | ft -auto | Where{$_.WorkspaceId -eq $GroupWorkspaceId} 

    clear-variable -name resultJson
    clear-variable -name resultObject

}
## END LOOP  ##################
#------------------------------------------------------ 

## Export user access for all workspaces
    $WorkspaceUsers | SORT Workspace, UserRole, displayName | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Note: You will only be able to get the workspace members if you are a member of the workspace. From an administrative perspective even a PowerBI admin won't be able to view the membership. @sherlockSpreadsheets do you have a workaround?